# Is Hibernate creating proxy or loading real entity in collections depending on previous queries?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

Is this some kind of Hibernate feature? If a proxy object was created and you iterate over other collection that contains it, then return that proxy. But if it was never loaded before, then load actual database representation?

Let's say, that instance of `A` has some elements in both sets `bs` and `cs` and each instance of `B` has property `c` set. Somewhere in the code I'm directly accessing `cs` property.
I noticed that if before accessing `cs` I iterate over `bs` elements, then `cs` contains proxies.
That does not happen, when I iterate over `cs` right after loading `A` instance.

It seems that `C` proxies are created and set when iterating over `bs` and the same proxy is later present when going through `cs`.

```
class A {
  Set<B> bs;
  Set<C> cs;
}


class B {
  C c;
}

class C {
  ...
}
```